# In which dimension did Rick and Morty end up in after they Cronenberg'd their home dimension?

Tags: rick-and-morty

There have been several instances where Rick has defined himself as being from Dimension C-137.

First in S02E02 ("Mortynight Run") when Rick identifies himself at the Jerry Day Care sign-in. And then later in that season at the Council of Ricks.

[image: a screen shot of the sign-in sheet of the Jerry Day Care, with Rick identifying his home dimension as C-137]

In S01E06 ("Rick Potion No. 9") Rick sloppily concocts a serum that turns the entire human population into Cronenberg monsters. They are forced to leave their home world to another dimension similar to that of theirs.

**Question**: Is it clear or are there any clues or easter eggs that tell us what dimension they moved to?

I don't believe their new dimension (C-XXX) is C-137, because in that same episode at the Jerry Daycare, we see that Rick fills Jerry's home dimension as N/A. I'm interpreting that as Rick knows his original dimension but doesn't know Jerry's.

Comment: I want to add that I dont believe their new dimension (C-XXX) is C-137, because in that same episode at the Jerry Daycare, we see that he fills Jerry's home dimension as N/A. I'm interpreting that as Rick knows his original dimension but doesn't know Jerry's. Either meaning he himself doesn't know C-XXX or doesn't know if C-XXX Rick did anything with C-XXX Jerry.

Comment: The 410th Chorp Dimension.

Comment: @dasMetzger: Actually, it's the opposite. Asking for Jerry's dimension after already having asked for Rick's dimension (on the form) would only be meaningful if this Jerry is from another dimension as this Rick. If Rick fills in "N/A", that means **it's not applicable to make this distinction** (which means that Rick is implicitly saying on the form that him and his Jerry are from the same dimension)

Comment: @dasMetzger: This doesn't exclude the possibility that Rick is lying on the form. But your inference that using "N/A" implies that Rick doesn't know Jerry's dimension seems unjustified as it would actually suggest the opposite.

Comment: I interpreted the "N/A" as "meh, who cares? It's a Jerry."

Comment: @BobGilmore: That's certainly not beyond the realm of possibilities, though that would make the form field consistently redundant (as Jerryboree is obviously tailed to Ricks, as only Jerries go there). Regardless of your interpretation or mine, it does seem unlikely that "N/A" is intended to mean "I don't know", because Rick uses a **question mark** later on to signal that he doesn't know (in the allergies checkbox). If he didn't know the dimension, you'd also expect a question mark in the "Jerry's dimension" field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Rick and Morty moved to the ["Replacement Dimension"](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/Replacement_Dimension) as it is called in most of the literature on the subject.

The Replacement Dimension is a parallel timeline so similar to C-137, Rick couldn't be bothered to give it a name. He chose it because that dimension's Rick and Morty had just killed themselves in an experiment. How convenient.

No further notation has currently surfaced on a mapping designation for the Replacement Dimension at this time.

**The Real Question on everyone's mind should be:** How did Rick C-137's portal gun/computer know where to find a conveniently dead or soon-to-be-dying Rick and Morty for Rick C-137 to slide into...?

Comment: Answer to "the real question" is the goggles he puts on before he says he needs to do some "scouting". They show up again in 'Rixty Minutes' with the explanation they show the POV of DNA matched alternate versions of the wearer.

Comment: As per the season 2 finale, Rick has a computer capable of finding a planet with the correct parameters (when the family looks for a new home). It stands to reason that Rick has a similar feature for dimensions. Don't expect a scientifically accurate answer.

Comment: **The Real Question** is, how many times has Rick already done this?

Answer (score 5):

This is going to be a confusing answer. So let me label the dimensions with a different name, which will help when you read the rest of the answer.

- **ND** - New dimension, where Rick and Morty jump to.
- **OD** - Old dimension, the one that gets Cronenberged.

The question now becomes: **which of these dimensions is C-137?**

---

### ND = C-137?

This seems the most likely, for a multitude of reasons:

- The show has never mentioned dimensions or any of their names until **after** R&M have already jumped from OD to ND.
- We first hear the name "C-137" from the Council of Ricks (in *Close Rickcounters of the Rick Kind*). Notice how it happens:

  - This takes place in ND.
  - The family is eating together.
  - The Council portals in, interrupt dinner, and *immediately* addresses Rick as "C-137". Their first line starts with ["Rick Sanchez of Earth Dimension C-137 ..."](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=364&t=19388)
  - Although not impossible, the Council has never shown to be aware that Rick is from another dimension (OD) than the one he is in (ND). It's highly likely that the Council was referring to Rick *by the dimension that he's currently inhabiting*.
- You linked to an image of Rick filling in a Jerryboree form. On the form, Rick lists his own dimension as C-137. This happens at a point in time where Rick is pretending to be ND Rick.

**But why does Rick fill in "N/A" for Jerry dimension? This doesn't make sense.**

Actually, it does make sense. Asking for Jerry's dimension after already having asked for Rick's dimension (on the form) would only be meaningful to fill in *if this Jerry is from another dimension as this Rick*.

If Rick fills in "N/A", that means it's **not applicable** to make this distinction, which means that Rick is implicitly saying on the form that him and his Jerry are from the same dimension.

This also makes sense. Rick and Morty are **hiding** the fact that they are from OD, and they consistently act as if they are from ND. It makes sense for Rick to put his assumed identity (ND, C-137) on a Jerryboree form.
(I would hazard a guess that the Council of Ricks members also make use of the Jerryboree.)

---

### OD = C-137?

There is little evidence that suggests OD must be C-137.

This is further compounded by the fact that we never hear the name "C-137" while our Rick and Morty are still in OD.

And then there's the fact that the Council of Ricks referred to our Rick as "Rick Sanchez of Earth Dimension C-137". If C-137 is actually OD, that would mean that the Council was *aware* that this Rick is the Rick from OD (and not from ND, where they came to get him).

**The Council couldn't have known that our Rick is from OD.**

Later, when they suspect our Rick of being guilty of the murders, the Council of Ricks wants to scan Rick's portal gun to ascertain where he has been:

> **Some Rick** -  Scan his portal gun!
>   **Our Rick** -  *Oh, come on. Don't look at another man's portal-gun history. We -- we all go to weird places.*
>   **Some Rick** -  Yes, but it appears you alone have been going to the exact timelines and locations in which the murders occurred.

This directly proves that the Council of Ricks needs to access the portal gun locally before they know where the portal gun has been. This means that they **cannot** be aware of Rick's travel history before they took him to the Citadel.

This means that when the Council of Ricks entered the scene and addressed our Rick as "Rick Sanchez of Earth Dimension C-137", they must have been unaware that Rick has travelled (as they have not yet scanned his portal gun), which further suggests that they are therefore referring to Rick by the **current** dimension's name.

---

### Conclusion

It's never explicitly confirmed, but it's highly likely that C-137 is the new dimension that Rick and Morty jump to after Cronenberging their home dimension.

Answer (score 3):

The new dimension is definitely NOT C-137. It may be that we have never seen his C-137. One instance is that in our plot, Rick abandoned Beth for 20 years, but during the episode with the evil Rick, we see that in our Rick's memory appears a young Morty. Our Rick is holding and playing with morty. Furthermore, in S03E01 after

> Rick escaped prison and tries to kill the council or Ricks, he says "she is not even my Summer" referring to the Summer of the dimension Rick transported after he Cronenberg'd the world.

So far there are no signs of what dimension he is, but I think that's the whole point. It does not matter for Rick where he goes. He probably lost his dimension long time ago, and now he is just hopping on other dimensions trying to survive.

Comment: It seems far more likely that the new dimension is actually C-137. When the Council of Ricks enters the dining room in _Close Rickcounters_, they _immediately_ refer to our Rick as "C-137" (upon exiting the portal), while they are not aware that our Rick is from a different dimension. There is more going on (like when you referred to Rick's memory of baby Morty, while actually having been absent according to Beth), but this  is not related as to which dimension actually is labeled C-137.

Comment: The Rick is indeed C-137, but that does not mean that the dimension in the series is his original dimension. Furthermore, when the last of the councils threatens to kill Summer, Rick responds "She is not even my original Summer". What I'm trying to say is that our Rick is from C-137, but throughout the show, we have never seen his original dimension.

Comment: How does "she is not my original Summer" help with indicating the name of either Rick's or Summer's dimension? It only establishes that Rick is from another dimension than Summer, which isn't really up for debate as we've seen Rick and Morty jump dimensions (it's part of the question's premise).

Comment: Also note that Rick having jumped dimensions before is an unproven fan theory, and your evidence is not irrefutable. E.g: Rick may have _visited_ another dimension to visit baby Morty, or Rick may have secretly visited his dimension's baby Morty without Beth knowing about it. Both are equally valid explanations for Rick having memories of baby Morty, without requiring Rick to have _migrated_ from one dimension to another.