# Which is dimension C-137 in Rick and Morty?

Tags: rick-and-morty

Was it the Cronenberg dimension or the one in which Rick and Morty are presently in now?

Comment: 3 across, 5 down

Comment: This is directly answered in the new season.

Comment: @TheAsh is correct. Currently, all answers made prior to September 2022 are incorrect and haven't been updated to reflect current information.

Answer (score 8):

## [The Cronenberg dimension](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/Dimension_C-137) probably

According to the Rick and Morty wikia page (questionable accuracy) states the C-137, the universe that is most commonly associated with the Rick and Morty pair we see is in fact the one overrun by Cronenbergs. Whether or not this is really C-137 we don't know as Rick could've destroyed a previous Earth, however as far as we've been led to believe it is C-137. Morty similarly states that he's the Morty from C-137, but whether this is due to his lack of knowledge or trust in Rick is unknown.

The dimension makes various appearances over later episodes in Rick's memories or other flashbacks.

[This previous question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126746/rick-morty-what-dimension-did-they-end-up-in-after-they-cronenbergd-their-ho) on our site shows us that the new dimension they enter is not C-137, but known as the ["Replacement Dimension"](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/Replacement_Dimension) in literature surrounding the show.

Comment: Not every dimension has always been separate (e.g. the dimensions always splitting in S02E01). E.g. if we're in one dimension now, and I flip a coin, this dimension splits into "ourdimension-heads" and "ourdimension-tails". Rick specifically chose the new dimension because it was so similar to their old one. That makes it highly likely that these two dimensions have only recently diverged and were one and the same until then. Therefore, the memories of "our" Rick and "blown up" Rick could be **identical** if the events occurred before the two dimensions were established as separate dimensions.

Comment: It also depends on the question... When did they leave the "the squirrels realized that morty found out that they actually rule the world" dimension? Chances are, that the question will get more and more complicated with time.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many Dimensions they leave if the Cronenberg dimension is THE C-137

Comment: This is an interesting wrinkle, but it appears in the most recent episode >! that the cronenburg dimension is not the first one they have left. One of Mortys purged memories mentions another previous one >

Comment: @alemus You've misunderstood that scene.  Rick specifically mentions how he's said "we can only do that so many times, Morty!"  Which is referring to his dialogue when they bailed on Cronenburg world for the new one.  Whether are not they then abandoned that world because of the squirrels is another matter. Possibly Rick negotiated the memory erasure to get them to back off (it shouldn't be too hard to convince them that he doesn't really care, or to fool them into thinking he forgot, too).

Answer (score 4):

This is going to be a confusing answer. So let me label the dimensions with a different name, which will help when you read the rest of the answer.

- **ND** - New dimension, where Rick and Morty jump to.
- **OD** - Old dimension, the one that gets Cronenberged.

The question now becomes: **which of these dimensions is C-137?**

---

### ND = C-137?

This seems the most likely, for a multitude of reasons:

- The show has never mentioned dimensions or any of their names until **after** R&M have already jumped from OD to ND.
- We first hear the name "C-137" from the Council of Ricks (in *Close Rickcounters of the Rick Kind*). Notice how it happens:

  - This takes place in ND.
  - The family is eating together.
  - The Council portals in, interrupt dinner, and *immediately* addresses Rick as "C-137". Their first line starts with ["Rick Sanchez of Earth Dimension C-137 ..."](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=364&t=19388)
  - Although not impossible, the Council has never shown to be aware that Rick is from another dimension (OD) than the one he is in (ND). It's highly likely that the Council was referring to Rick *by the dimension that he's currently inhabiting*.
- On the Jerryboree form, Rick lists his own dimension as C-137. This happens at a point in time where Rick is pretending to be ND Rick.

---

### OD = C-137?

There is little evidence that suggests OD must be C-137.

This is further compounded by the fact that we never hear the name "C-137" while our Rick and Morty are still in OD.

And then there's the fact that the Council of Ricks referred to our Rick as "Rick Sanchez of Earth Dimension C-137". If C-137 is actually OD, that would mean that the Council was *aware* that this Rick is the Rick from OD (and not from ND, where they came to get him).

**The Council couldn't have known that our Rick is from OD.**

Later, when they suspect our Rick of being guilty of the murders, the Council of Ricks wants to scan Rick's portal gun to ascertain where he has been:

> **Some Rick** -  Scan his portal gun!
>   **Our Rick** -  *Oh, come on. Don't look at another man's portal-gun history. We -- we all go to weird places.*
>   **Some Rick** -  Yes, but it appears you alone have been going to the exact timelines and locations in which the murders occurred.

This directly proves that the Council of Ricks needs to access the portal gun locally before they know where the portal gun has been. This means that they **cannot** be aware of Rick's travel history before they took him to the Citadel.

This means that when the Council of Ricks entered the scene and addressed our Rick as "Rick Sanchez of Earth Dimension C-137", they must have been unaware that Rick has travelled (as they have not yet scanned his portal gun), which further suggests that they are therefore referring to Rick by the **current** dimension's name.

---

### Conclusion

It's never explicitly confirmed, but it's highly likely that C-137 is the new dimension that Rick and Morty jump to after Cronenberging their home dimension.

Comment: You say "_The Council couldn't have known that our Rick is from OD._" Except they seem to suggest quite often they know which Rick is which without needing identification. If this is the "Rick from Earth C-137" then that's confirmation of his original dimension, as the Rick from ND would be dead.

Comment: @Edlothiad: Like I said in my question, it's never explicitly confirmed. But your suggestion (OD = C-137) hinges on an unspoken, unacknowledged, unconfirmed skill whereby each Rick knows each other Rick personally. While there are cases of some Ricks knowing other Ricks, that's still a massive jump to assume that every Rick knows every other Rick. Especially our Rick, who has always shied away from the Council and has not been social around Ricks in general. Your suggestion would also require our Rick to reveal his true (hidden) origins on a Jerryboree form.

Comment: @Edlothiad: That also doesn't explain how the Ricks found our Rick in the new dimension. How can they be aware of his location, if they already need his portal gun to see where he has travelled? If they know where Rick is, then they must invariably keep track of each Rick's whereabouts (especially the Ricks who have acted against the Council, which we know is the case for our Rick)

Comment: @Falter don't they pick him up at his house, it doesn't exactly require that great a survalence operation to know he's "at his house"

Comment: Season 3 Episode 8 (Morty's Mind Blowers) had a clip where Rick creates a device that let's Morty talk to animals. Morty angers the squirrels and Rick talks about going to a 'replacement dimension'. The answer to the question is probably none of the above.

Comment: @user20310: I was rather focusing on _which dimension_ they found him in, rather than the location inside the dimension itself.

Comment: @Flater Depends when he did the things that angered the council, couldn't he have done those things as C-137 rick?

Comment: @user20310: We're talking about two different things. So I'll elaborate on my point. **Regardless of past interactions**, the Council of Ricks decided they needed to talk to C-137 Rick. If you argue that the old (Cronenberged) dimension is C-137, that means that the council intentionally went to another dimension (the one Rick migrated **to**). But how did they know which dimension to find him in? As I've proven in the question, the Council must scan the portal gun to know where a Rick has been, they don't know it before they do so. So how could they have known in which dimension he was?

Comment: @Flater C-137 also specifically mentions that "one Morty is good enough to hide from the Galactic Government", but to evade the Council of Ricks requires, say, an entire dome of tortured Mortys (or a few, a car battery, and some jumper cables). The council's tracking abilities are far superior. C-137 is also mentioned as a well-known trouble-making rogue Rick, and that's why he was their first suspect. He's not some random Rick among millions. He is a specific, notable Rick that has already been a subject of their attention.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not.

In S06E01, it is made clear that C-137 is the dimension from the flashback, and not the Cronenberg dimension.

Instead, the Cronenberg dimension

> is home to to the new antagonist in the series, "Prime Rick" (AKA the Rick who killed Rick C-137's family.)

This [excellent reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/rickandmorty/comments/x8lp2x/dimension_status/) summarizes it well (spoilers)

> C137 DIMENSION.
> (The earth in this dimension is currently stuck in a loop since 30 years and is the origin place of our Rick):
>
> - RICK - Alive but not in the same dimension currently.
> - Beth - Dead.
> - Morty - Non existent.
> - Summer - Non existent.
> - Jerry - Exists but not part of the show currently.

> CRONENBERG DIMENSION.
> (The earth on this dimension has no survivors and is the origin place of Rick prime and Our Morty):
>
> - Rick - Alive.
> - Beth - dead.
> - Morty - Alive but not in the same dimension currently.
> - Summer - dead.
> - Jerry - dead.

> REPLACEMENT DIMENSION.
> (The earth on this dimension is frundled and is the origin place of Our Beth and summer):
>
> - Rick - dead.
> - Beth - Alive but not in the same dimension currently.
> - Morty - dead.
> - Summer - Alive but not in the same dimension currently.
> - Jerry - frundled.

> NO-DIVORCE DIMENSION.
> (This is the only Dimension so far where Earth had no impact is the origin place of Our Jerry):
>
> - Rick - alive.
> - Beth - alive.
> - Morty - alive.
> - Summer - alive.
> - Jerry - alive but not in the same dimension currently.

> PARMESAN DIMENSION.
> (This is where everyone from different dimensions are currently):
>
> - Rick - dead.
> - Beth - dead.
> - Morty - dead.
> - Summer - dead.
> - Jerry - dead.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**
Ricks are too smart to be fooled by a Rick assuming the role of another Rick, so when they refer to C-137 as his name, that's because *he is Rick from C-137*.

**We don't know**

But, we *do* know that (at least Rick) *is* C-137 Rick.

From S01E10, **Close Rick-counters of the Rick Kind**, Rick (C-137) is recognized as "*of all the Ricks within the central finite curve, you're the malcontent*" with a "*history of non-cooperation with the Council.*" The Council is well aware of this Rick, and Rick is also aware of it: "*Why am I the first Rick you pull in every time a Rick stubs his toe?*"

If our Rick is just *pretending* to be C-137, where would he know that C-137 was against the Council, and why would he go along with it? If both our Rick *and* C-137 were anti-council, it's not like the Council wouldn't keep track of both of them.  The cursory scanning Rick did of universes at the end of **Rick Potion #9** would likely not furnish this information, and as Rick is *anti-Rick*, it's not like he'd even bother keeping a database.

Like the database that Evil Morty uses in the same episode to lure Rick into this trap.  It was probably EM's plan that Rick would not escape the Citadel, but even after Rick confronts the mind-controlled Rick, EM lays most of it on the line, to how he planned this to set-up Rick.

Although, the Rick database might have only told EM *which* Rick was best to frame, but not where he was, right? Unless there is a way to find where Ricks are, from Rick's own mouth: "*Well, one Morty is enough to hide from the bureaucrats*, but you get [...] a whole matrix of Mortys and put them in agonizing pain and that creates a pattern that can hide even from other Ricks...*" And the aforementioned scanning at the end of **Rick Potion #9** show that *at least* our Rick has a way to scan for other Ricks.

Evil Morty knows that C-137 Rick has a history of disagreement with the Council, and knows enough about where to find him to *hack his portal gun remotely*. It doesn't seem difficult to find where a Rick *is* then, maybe just where he *has* been, which is why the Council needed his portal gun to convict.

So why don't we know that the Cronenberg universe is C-137? Because we have no information available to corroborate.  We see in S03E08, **Morty's Mind Blowers**, that Rick and (this) Morty have had to change universes at least once before, but we have no idea how many times before (or since) that they might have.  We also aren't sure that when we meet Rick that we are meeting him in his home universe, as previous to the S01E01 **Pilot**, Rick had been away for four years- it's all conjecture at this point.  Rick could be the same Rick from that universe **or** Rick could have jumped to that universe after *probably* losing his daughter in his previous universe, given his attachment to Beth (despite his words at the end of S03E03 **Pickle Rick**, "*my access to infinite timelines precludes the necessity of attachment*").

Not to mention that Rick seems very capable of pulling off a universe change (from **Rick Potion #9**), telling Morty that "*It's not like we can do this every week, anyways. We get three or four more of these, tops.*" How would Rick know that there are so few times they could do this? If there are infinite universes, they should be able to do this infinite times, unless there is some knowledge that Rick knows about the process, perhaps because he's done it before?

So, Rick is C-137 Rick, **Rick Potion #9** universe *might not* be C-137, but we just don't have enough information to go on.

*Bureaucrats meaning here the Galactic Central Government

===================================================

**Update!**

@Flater pointed out in a comment below that Rick fooled Ricks in S03E01. And...yeah. That's 100% a thing. -_-

...But then, S03E07, the Rick & Morty trying to collect funds from *our* Rick and Morty somehow have on their clipboard that this Rick is the Rick responsible for the destruction of the Citadel. A quote from S01E10 that I was looking for a place to use was "*"Ricks have a very distinctive and traceable brainwave due to our genius.*", which I guess means that even though the *body* might be different, the mind of individual Ricks would be the same across body swaps. So, maybe Ricks are fooled by Ricks assuming a different Rick's look, but doing a brainscan lets you know who the real Rick is. I am interested now if C-137 gets used in any other episode of Season 3?

Comment: I would update my answer, but that wouldn't be fair as it would affect the people who voted on my answer (which at the time seemed a pretty reasonable claim for me to make. But I think your answer is the most complete and accurate, +1 from me!

Comment: "Ricks are too smart to be fooled by a Rick assuming the role of another Rick" Yet that is exactly what happened in S03E01.

Comment: @Flater excellent point, updated answer

Comment: Rick stating a limit on jumping realities is most likely a fourth wall break. He's asserting the nature of the show: the show does not involve being written episodically, writing off incongruities with "they changed realities"; but that jumping between base realities is a major story-telling device that has serious implications and cannot be overused without disillusioning the audience.  Which is not to wholly rule out that they won't give it an in-universe explanation, or aren't happy implying there is one, but the show's nature makes a fourth wall break a very likely explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's not forget the

> "*The squirrels realized that morty found out that they actually rule the world*"

dimension (which they had to flee from), which was very likely their home at some point after they left their old Cronenberg'd dimension (since Rick references his statement that they can only "do this" - moving dimensions - a few times). So, depending on when this happened, that world was C-137. Or the one after. This is really getting complicated.

Comment: That should probably be spoiler tagged using ">!" because not everyone has seen the latest episode!

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if the writers were aware of this debate and threw in that clip just to troll internet message boards. Seems like something they would do.

Comment: I don't think it could have been before the Cronenberg dimension because it had the crack around the perimeter of their house from when their party accidentally transported them to another world. This definitely happened after Rick and Morty abandoned the Cronenberg dimension.

Comment: Well spotted, @TBear.